# Text file line doesn't match with string indexOf()

Tags: javascript, string, file, google-chrome-extension, indexof

My Chrome extension will show if a link in a text file matches any link in current tab's html. The text file is like-

```
https://www.facebook.com/groups/929402513755249/
https%3A%2F%2Ficpc.baylor.edu%2F
https%3A%2F%2Fvjudge.net%2Fcontest%2F187074
```

My content.js is -

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', chrome.extension.getURL('file.txt'), true);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200)
            {
                var allText = xhr.responseText;
                //var lines = allText.split('\n');

                for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
                    var link= document.links[i].href;
                    var lines = allText.split('\n');

                    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
                        console.log(link);   // prints: https://www.facebook.com/groups/929402513755249/#
                        console.log(lines[line]);   //prints: https://www.facebook.com/groups/929402513755249/
                        var linestr = lines[line];
                        console.log(link.indexOf(linestr));  // prints: -1
                        console.log(link.indexOf("https://www.facebook.com/groups/929402513755249/") !== -1);  // prints: true
                        if(link.indexOf(lines[line]) !== -1)
                        {
                            console.log("Link Matched!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
```

I can't understand why `link.indexOf(lines[line])` is -1 when link is `https://www.facebook.com/groups/929402513755249/#` and `lines[line]` is `https://www.facebook.com/groups/929402513755249/`. But `link.indexOf("https://www.facebook.com/groups/929402513755249/")` returns 0 as index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows (or at least editing the text file on Windows), the lines might be separated by `\r\n` rather than just `\n`; if that's the case, then the lines will all end in `\r`, whereas the links won't, so it will never match.  Try `allText.split(/\r?\n/)` instead of `split('\n')`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to chridd's answer, also try trimming the split string values before looking for a match,

```
var linestr = lines[line].trim();
```